# Render values from array of objects which contains an object (React, Typescript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, object

I'm trying to print, for example, the Names on some  in my TSX.
Data has this form :

```js
const targets: {
    [key: string]: {
        [key: string]: string[]
    }
}[] = [
    {
        '0665496f-7a4e-46b6-a922-2d42ce205c03': {
            names: ['Hello', 'World'],
            dob: ['1971-09-01'],
        },
    },
    {
        '2679d2b8-9c25-44e3-bfad-3e2ef6b93b94': {
            names: ['Jordan'],
        },
    },
    {
        '8a8b7630-5bc8-443e-a88d-c1601659b39e': {
            names: ['John Doe'],
        },
    },
]
```

How can I do it the more efficient way ? The code I tried is very complicated, I'm pretty sure I'm doing it wrong...

Here's what I need for output, for example for the first object :

```html
<div>
    <input data-profile-id="0665496f-7a4e-46b6-a922-2d42ce205c03" data-key="names" type="checkbox" />
    <label>Hello</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input data-profile-id="0665496f-7a4e-46b6-a922-2d42ce205c03" data-key="names" type="checkbox" />
    <label>World</label>
</div>
```

I need this infos in dataset to handle click on those inputs.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, target is an array, map it's objects inside, get the key and value of each object.

Use the key to set it in **data-profile-id** while the **value** holds another object which contains **names** and **dob**. Map the array of **names** to get all the names inside the array.

```
targets.map( target => {
  const [key, value] = Object.entries( target )[0]
  return (
    <div>
      {
        value.names?.map( name => 
        <>
          <input data-profile-id={key} data-key="names" type="checkbox" />
          <label>{name}</label>
        </> 
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
} )
```

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot ;) Only a [0] was missing at the end of line 2, like this : const [key, value] = Object.entries(target)[0]

Comment: My apologies, you are correct. I have fixed it like you said, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For js/ts-only answer you might want to check this out:

```js
const d = [
    {
        '0665496f-7a4e-46b6-a922-2d42ce205c03': {
            names: ['Hello', 'World'],
            dob: ['1971-09-01'],
        },
    },
    {
        '2679d2b8-9c25-44e3-bfad-3e2ef6b93b94': {
            names: ['Jordan'],
        },
    },
    {
        '8a8b7630-5bc8-443e-a88d-c1601659b39e': {
            names: ['John Doe'],
        },
    },
];

const create = (id, txt) => {
  const d = document.createElement("div"),    // creating outer div
        i = document.createElement("input"),  // creating input
        l = document.createElement("label");  // creating label
  l.innerText = txt;
  i.setAttribute("data-profile-id", id);      // set data.id
  i.setAttribute("data-key", "names");        // ...
  i.type = "checkbox";
  d.appendChild(i);
  d.appendChild(l);
  return d;                                   // return
}
d.forEach(e => Object.keys(e).forEach(a => e[a].names.forEach(b => document.body.appendChild(create(a, b)))));   // loop over array and add to body
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```